# Display dynamically created pdf embedded in browser (IE9)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, internet-explorer

I am trying to display a dynamically created PDF (Byte()) loading the default viewer int he client browser.  The following code works with all browsers except the microsoft ones consistently.  IE9 Wants to run MSXML 3.0 SP11 in response to the page.  Here is the code generating the page:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

Dim pdfData() As Byte
  'load PDF Data

If pdfData.Length < 1 Then
 Response.Write("ERROR - No data")
 Response.End()

Return
 End If

Response.Clear()
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=newcomp.PDF")
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", pdfData.Length.ToString())
 Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache")
 Response.ContentType ="application/pdf"
 Response.BinaryWrite(pdfData)

Response.Flush()
 HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()

End Sub
```

I call the page like this: http://localhost/DisplayPdf.aspx?newcomp.pdf

You can try it yourself with this link: http://www.netvaluecentral.com/DisplayPdf.aspx?newcomp.pdf

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you remove the Content-Disposition header?

Comment: Also, trying your link it does try and open the file in Adobe Reader in IE but reports, "The file is damaged". So perhaps your generated PDF content is not a valid PDF document?

Comment: It works in ALL other browsers (Firefox, Opera, Chrome).  The direct link loads a pdf file into memory instead of going through the dynamic pdf generation for testing purposes.  Same issue if I remove the Content-Disposition header, except that when I do that, the other browsers attempt to download the pdf instead of open within the browser.

Comment: I've tried it in a few browsers and Adobe Reader launches but then reports "The file is damaged and could not be repaired". If you think it's fine, then OK, I'm just telling you what I see.

Comment: What version of Adobe?  I use Foxit Reader for testing.

Comment: I use Foxit at home, too, but I'm at work stuck on an old PC which has Adobe Reader 9.4.1 on it. I also tried it on a PC with Adobe Reader 8 on it, with same error. Sorry, don't have latest (10) to try.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that confirmation.  Apparently Adobe doesn't like that file, but Foxit has not problem with it.  Also I have determined it is a bug in the Foxit reader plugin with IE9 and have reported it with them.  The page works fine with Adobe.  Thanx for your help with this.